# How to fix XXE vulnerability in XPathDocument use in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, fortify, xxe

Fortify shows XXE vulnerabilty exists for the below code in C#:

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(filePath);
```

Kindly help me how to fix the issue

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://portswigger.net/web-security/xxe) will give you some pointers

Answer (score 0):

Extract from [OWASP Cheat Sheets on XXE](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html):

`System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator` is unsafe by default in .NET Framework versions prior to 4.5.2.

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("example.xml");
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(reader);
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
string xml = nav.InnerXml.ToString();
```